# Illegal token on line 16

Tags: javascript

I'm using this script I found on the nets as a test and I keep getting this illegal token error.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    done();
});

function done() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        updates();
        done();
    }, 200);
}

function updates() {
    $.getJSON(“fetch.php”, function(data) {
        $(“ul”).empty();
        $.each(data.result, function(){
            $(“ul”).append(“Name: “+this['name']+”Age: “+this['age']+”Company:             “+this['company']+”");
        });
    });
}
```

Also how would I get this to work?
   $("ul").append("

Comment: If this code was copied from a web source or blog post or something, be very careful when copying code.  Many CMS have the bad habit of converting real quotes `"` into curly quotes for presentation `“` which are not valid for code.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Careful with that edit! You "improved formatting" on the code which was causing the issue, erasing the problem.

Comment: I see, I didn't bother to check the actual question, I just improved someone else's edit suggestion. >_>

Answer (score 6):

You have "fancy curly" quotes `“”` instead of plain quotes `""` all over your code

```
$.getJSON(“fetch.php”, function(data) {
         ^^^        ^^^
```

should look like

```
$.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
         ^^^        ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! One last thing how would I get this to work?    $("ul").append("<div class=""progress progress-success""><div style=""width: "+this['health']+""%"+");

Comment: append an actual li element

Answer (score 1):

Think could be the **“**, change ir to **"**.

Answer (score 0):

@epascarello is correct. jQuery does not accept this type of quotes ( `“ul”` for example). Have in mind that you can only use the single quetes `''` or the double quotes `""`.